# Ambiguous partial specializations with Clang in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, template-specialization

```
template <typename Foo, Foo Part>
struct TSelect {};

enum What {
    The
};

template <typename Foo>
struct AnotherOneSelector {
    static constexpr Foo Id = Foo::The;
};

template <typename Foo, typename SelectPartType>
struct THelper;

template <typename Foo>
struct THelper<Foo, TSelect<Foo, AnotherOneSelector<Foo>::Id>> {};

template <typename Foo, Foo PartId>
struct THelper<Foo, TSelect<Foo, PartId>> {};

int main() {
    THelper<What, TSelect<What, What::The>> t;
}
```

This code compiles with gcc8.1 with each of the standard option (c++11, c++14, c++17), but clang trunk does not with [c++17](https://godbolt.org/g/meRZ8r) (although with [c++14](https://godbolt.org/g/m9qEds) everything is fine).

Message error is:

```
test.cpp:23:49: error: ambiguous partial specializations of 'THelper<What, TSelect<What, The> >'
        THelper<What, TSelect<What, What::The>> t;
                                                ^
test.cpp:17:12: note: partial specialization matches [with Foo = What]
    struct THelper<Foo, TSelect<Foo, AnotherOneSelector<Foo>::Id>> {};
           ^
test.cpp:20:12: note: partial specialization matches [with Foo = What, PartId = The]
    struct THelper<Foo, TSelect<Foo, PartId>> {};
           ^
1 error generated.
```

Which compiler is correct? I haven't seen any changes in template 
specialization in C++17.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++17 difference here is that you can deduce the type of a non-type parameter from the corresponding argument. And Clang is apparently doing the deduction wrong.

As relevant here, you are supposed to synthesize a unique type for `Foo` and try to deduce the `Foo` and `PartId` in `THelper<Foo, TSelect<Foo, PartId>>` against `THelper<Unique, TSelect<Unique, AnotherOneSelector<Unique>::Id>>`. What seems to be happening is that Clang treats `AnotherOneSelector<Unique>::Id` to have some separate unique type - call it `Unique2`- so that the deduction fails in C++17 because you deduced conflicting types for `Foo`. The handling of non-deduced contexts like this is notoriously underspecified, but I'm pretty sure it's meant to deduce using the converted template argument's type rather than the original.

Two possible workarounds are:

- Suppress deduction of `Foo` from the non-type argument by wrapping the type into a non-deduced context. For example: `template <typename Foo, std::remove_const_t<Foo> PartId>`.
- Force the conversion to `Foo` in the template argument to avoid the spurious conflict: `struct THelper<Foo, TSelect<Foo, Foo{AnotherOneSelector<Foo>::Id}>>`

Comment: Fun fact that with the second workaround gcc fails in `internal compiler error` :)