# Auto non-type template parameter: ambiguous partial specializations in Clang

Tags: c++, templates, clang, c++17, auto

Clang (7, 8, trunk) rejects the following code

```
enum class E {};
inline static constexpr auto e = E{};
// inline static constexpr auto e = nullptr;

template<auto, int> class S;
template<int a, int b> class S<a, b> {};
template<int b> class S<e, b> {};

int main() {
    S<0, 0> s;
}
```

with an error:

> ```
> error: ambiguous partial specializations of 'S<0, 0>'
> note: partial specialization matches [with a = 0, b = 0]
> template<int a, int b> class S<a, b> {};
>                              ^
> note: partial specialization matches [with b = 0]
> template<int b> class S<e, b> {};
>                       ^
> ```

1. Why is it ambiguous? How can `e` match `0`? If I replace `E{}` with `nullptr`, Clang stops complaining. This looks like a Clang's bug. GCC compiles it just fine.
2. If it is a bug, what is a workaround? In my case, the `auto` parameter can be either `E` (and only one value `E{}`) or `int`. Then:

   ```
   template<auto, int, typename> class S_impl;
   template<int a, int b> class S_impl<a, b, int> {};
   template<int b> class S_impl<e, b, E> {};

   template<auto a, int b> using S = S_impl<a, b, decltype(a)>;
   ```

   Is there a more succinct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang is doing the deduction wrong. It is similar to [this bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38027), linked to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126940/ambiguous-partial-specializations-with-clang-in-c17) (not exactly identical as you are using auto in template parameters which will prevent you to compile using stdc++14).

An interesting case is that it is not the case if it's a complete specialization; only on partial specialization :

```
#include <iostream>

enum class E {};
inline static constexpr auto e = E{};

template <auto a, int b>
class FOO;
template <int a, int b > class FOO<a, b> {};
template <int b> class FOO<e, b> {};

template <auto a, int b>
class BAR;
template <int a, int b > class BAR<a, b> {};
template <> class BAR<e, 0> {};

template <auto a>
class BAZ;
template <int a> class BAZ<a> {};
template <> class BAZ<e> {};

int main() {
    // FOO <0, 0> foo; // <= Not Ok
    BAR<0, 0> bar; // <= Ok
    BAZ<0> baz; // <= Ok
}
```

Any solution that force the deduction of the type template parameter will work therefore your suggested solution is perfectly valid. IMHO, I would avoid using auto in template parameter when not necessary to improve readability :

```
template <typename T, T value, int> class S_impl; // <= this auto is not necessary
template <int a, int b> class S_impl<int, a, b> {};
template <int b> class S_impl<E, e, b> {};
// Either define S to use S<0,0> or directly use S_impl<int, 0, 0>
template <auto a, int b> using S = S_impl<decltype(a), a, b> // <= this auto is necessary
```